# Values inserted in hive table with double quotes for string from csv file

Tags: sql, csv, hadoop, hive

I am exporting a csv file into hive table.
about the csv file : column values are enclosed within double-quotes , seperated by comma .

**Sample record from csv**

```
"4","good"
"3","not bad"
"1","very worst"
```

I created a hive table with the following statement,

create external table currys(review_rating string,review_comment string ) row format fields delimited by `','`;

**Table created .**

now I loaded the data using the command load data local inpath and it was successful.
when I query the table,

```
select * from currys;
```

**The result is :**

```
"4"  "good"
"3"  "not bad"
"1"   "very worst"
```

instead of

```
4  good
3  not bad
1  very worst
```

records are inserted with double-quotes which shouldnt be.

Please let me know how to get rid of this double quote .. any help or guidance is highly appreciated...

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: The behaviour is appropriate since your separator is `,` and you do nothing to remove the `"`

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061466/how-to-handle-fields-enclosed-within-quotescsv-in-importing-data-from-s3-into) too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using any `serde`? If so, then you can write a `regex` command in the `SERDE PROPERTIES` to remove the quotes.

Or you can use the `csv-serde` from [here](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) and define the `quote character`.