# hive string comparison is not returning any values

Tags: hive, hiveql

When trying to select only columns where a string is equal to a value in Hive I am returned an empty value.

#### The schema of the table is as follows:

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
a                       string                                  
b                       int                                     
c                       int
```

#### The contents of the table are as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
"more"  10  30
"dur"   11  30
"vowww" 13  30
```

#### Now I try to query for where a="more"

The SELECT ... WHERE query I am running is:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a='more'`

#### The returned value is empty

I have also tried:

To see if double quotes work, if querying for other column values work (it doesnt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st try wild card to see whether it is fetching records or not

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a like '%more%'
```

then if it is fetching records

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a='"more"'
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of your Query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
"more"  10  30
"dur"   11  30
"vowww" 13  30
```

This query will return the proper values:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a='"more"'
```

you should remove the `"` using `regex`. 
Please consider reading this answer
[Values inserted in hive table with double quotes for string from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23822565/4391011)