# How to load CSV data with enclosed by double quotes and separated by tab into HIVE table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load data from a csv file in which the values are enclosed by double quotes '"' and tab separated '\t' .
But when I try to load that into hive its not throwing any error and data is loaded without any error but I think all the data is getting loaded into a single column and most of the values it showing as NULL.
below is my create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
organization  STRING,
order BIGINT,
created_on  TIMESTAMP,
issue_date TIMESTAMP,
qty  INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ESCAPED BY '"'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Input file sample;-

```
 "Organization" "Order"  "Created on"   "issue_date"   "qty"
 "GB"   "111223"    "2015/02/06 00:00:00"   "2015/05/15 00:00:00"   "5"
 "UK"   "1110"  "2015/05/06 00:00:00"   "2015/06/1 00:00:00"   "51"
```

and Load statement to push data into hive table.

```
 LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/example.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE example
```

What could be the issue and how can I ignore header of the file.
and if I remove   ESCAPED BY '"' from create statement its loading in respective columns but all the values are enclosed by double quotes.
How can I remove double quotes from values and ignore header of the file?

Comment: Are you running HUE? In this case you could you the metastore manager webapp.

Answer (score 28):

You can now use [OpenCSVSerde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde) which allows you to define the separator character and easily escape surrounding double-quotes :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example (
   organization  STRING,
   order BIGINT,
   created_on  TIMESTAMP,
   issue_date TIMESTAMP,
   qty  INT
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)  
LOCATION '/your/folder/location/';
```

Comment: "This SerDe treats all columns to be of type String. Even if you create a table with non-string column types using this SerDe, the DESCRIBE TABLE output would show string column type. The type information is retrieved from the SerDe. To convert columns to the desired type in a table, you can create a view over the table that does the CAST to the desired type." Is there an alternative way in which I don't have to create a subsequent view?

Comment: For any newbies out there (myself included), in case you don't know "SerDe" stands for Serializer/Deserializer.  Here's some very helpful info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe

Comment: Upvote :) Answer will be complete if you add tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1") before semi colon.

Comment: Hi, this openSCVSerde doesnt cater nulls. How do you treat null values here. Reference to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020631/aws-athena-null-values-are-replaced-by-n-after-table-is-created-how-to-keep-the?noredirect=1#comment107956665_61020631

Comment: @cheseaux I have csv file with double quotes                                                                                  
e.g "ABC",9,10,"X,Y",88 
I want to load this as is in hive table with columns (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
so when I do select c1,c2,c4 it should give output "ABC" 9 "X,U" 
that is I want output with double quotes, is it possible

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `escaped by`, that's for escape characters, not quote characters. I don't think that Hive actually has support for quote characters. You might want to take a look at [this csv serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) which accepts a quotechar property.

Also if you have HUE, you can use the metastore manager webapp to load the CSV in, this will deal with the header row, column datatypes and so on.

Comment: thanks for quick reply but if I remove   ESCAPED BY '"' from create statement its loading in respective columns but all the values are enclosed by double quotes.

Comment: yes that's unfortnately true. you can use the csv serde to get around that issue, or you could also do  `replace(column, '"', '')` when you select from each of your columns to remove the double quotes.

Comment: it should be `regexp_replace(column, '"', '')`, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Comment: For any newbies out there (myself included), in case you don't know "SerDe" stands for Serializer/Deserializer.  Here's some very helpful info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSV Serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) to create the table. I've created a table in hive as follows, and it works like charm.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (
id STRING,
url STRING,
name STRING
)
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties ("separatorChar" = "\t")
LOCATION '<folder location>';
```

Comment: For any newbies out there (myself included), in case you don't know "SerDe" stands for Serializer/Deserializer.  Here's some very helpful info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe

Answer (score 0):

"Hive now includes an OpenCSVSerde which will properly parse those quoted fields without adding additional jars or error prone and slow regex."

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

source = Ben Doerr

[How to handle fields enclosed within quotes(CSV) in importing data from S3 into DynamoDB using EMR/Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061466/how-to-handle-fields-enclosed-within-quotescsv-in-importing-data-from-s3-into)

Comment: For any newbies out there (myself included), in case you don't know "SerDe" stands for Serializer/Deserializer.  Here's some very helpful info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe

Answer (score -2):

You can use a CSV serde " csv-serde-1.1.2.jar " to load the file without double quotes.

download link:

http://ogrodnek.github.io/csv-serde/

and the create table statement as

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> (col_name_1 type1, col_name_2 type2, ...) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde';
```

you can remove the header with the following property in the create table stmt

```
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: This serde is built in now

Comment: @Marcin re: "this serde is built in now"...is this why the csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar link does not work anymore from the source (https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde)?  How do I get the SerDe working in Hue's "Metastore Tables" now?