# how to load csv file into hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hiveql

this is my csv file

```
id,name,address

"1xz","hari","streetno=1-23-2,street name=Lakehill,town=Washington"
"2xz","giri","streetno=5-6-3456,street name=second street,town=canada"
```

i was loaded this data using row format delimeter "," but it was not loading properley,i am facing the  problem with address filed.in address field i have data like this format **"streetno=1-23-2,street name=Lakehill,town=Washington"**  in this address filed values are terminated by again ",".i was found one solution in pig,help me  to solve it using hive.

i am getting this output

```
 "1xz"   "hari"   "streetno=1-23-2
 "2xz"   "giri"   "streetno=5-6-3456
```

this is my schema

```
create table emps (id string,name string,addresss string ) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;
```

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637536/how-to-load-csv-data-with-enclosed-by-double-quotes-and-separated-by-tab-into-hi

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` function, it returns array of strings: [0]='streetno', [1]='1-23-2':

```
split(address,'=')[1]  as address --returns '1-23-2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found a working solution in Pig so why not transfer that relation to a Hive table directly using HCatalog.

```
STORE pig_relation INTO 'hive_table_name' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Make sure you start up Pig using:

```
>pig -useHCatalog
```

Table must already exist in Hive.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a string, b string, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL