# hive data load from double quote enclosed csv file format

Tags: python, shell, hadoop, hive, paramiko

My query is not working according to this post [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637536/how-to-load-csv-data-with-enclosed-by-double-quotes-and-separated-by-tab-into-hi)

Used the below command with the sql. But im not executing from shell. The sql is created as a string in python and passed to hive using paramiko. In shell it works fine. But when passed as as string from python im getting a bash error. It looks like some character escape issue.

Im trying to load csv file with each column value enclosed in double quotes.

```
   strsql='''create table temp(col1 INT,col2 string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("quoteChar" = "\"") tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1'); '''
```

Error

```
["bash: -c: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''\n", 'bash: -c: line 5: syntax error: unexpe                                                                                   cted end of file\n']
```

The i changed to `("quoteChar" = "\\"")` to add extra slash. Then i get a sql error

```
:FAILED: ParseException line 4:38 cannot recognize input near 'quoteChar' '=' ')' i                                                                                   n table properties list
```

**On further inspection the hive command is called with some extract properties as below. Could that be an issue?**

```
hive -e set hive.cli.print.header=true;hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column;hvesql;
```

Comment: your declaration should be: `strsql='''create table temp(col1 INT,col2 string) ROW FORMAT SERDE '\''org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'\'' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("quoteChar" = "\"") tblproperties ('\''skip.header.line.count'\''='\''1'\''); '''`

Comment: Triple quotes in Bash don't exist last time I checked. If the variable is defined in Python, it's still passed unescaped into Bash

Comment: no luck. changed as @RonakPatel suggested .and for quotechar as well  `ROW FORMAT SERDE '\''org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'\''
                WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('\''quoteChar'\'' = '\"') tblproperties ('\''skip.header.line.count'\''='\''1'\'');'''`

Comment: the error now is `bash: -c: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the sql should contain double quotes. as below. So as Ronak mentioned in comment the the double quotes should be escaped.

```
 ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
                WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("quoteChar" = '"') tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

So when sent as a string variable from outside shell it should be escaped as below. Need to use double slash

```
 ROW FORMAT SERDE \\"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde\\"
                WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (\\"quoteChar\\" = '\\"') tblproperties (\\"skip.header.line.count\\"=\\"1\\")
```

kinda simple. but took a lot to figure out :)