# how to insert csv file in hive table using multidelimeter

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to insert csv data in hive table

```
insert into googlereview
SELECT final.fields[0],final.fields[1],final.fields[2],final.fields[3],final.fields[4] from (SELECT split(line, '\\s+') as fields from googlereviewtemp) final;
```

i have data as below:

```
"abc,xyz",pos,pos,pos,pos
```

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you want to see as the final result? Do you need to remove quotes and separate fields by comma?

Comment: i want to insert data as below: abc,xyz in column 1 , pos in column 2, pos in column 3 ,pos in column 4 ,pos in column 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCSVSerde which allows you to define the separator character and easily escape surrounding double-quotes
here is the already give answer: [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637536/how-to-load-csv-data-with-enclosed-by-double-quotes-and-separated-by-tab-into-hi), change required separatorChar as "separatorChar" = ","