# AWS Athena null values are replaced by N after table is created. How to keep them as it is?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-athena

I'm creating a table in Athena from csv data in S3. The data has some columns quoted, so I use:

```
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",",
  'serialization.null.format' = '')
```

The serde works fine but then the null values in the resultant table are replaced with N. How can I keep the null values as empty or like Null etc, but not as N.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Not familiar with Athena, but some applications have display options around how you want NULL values displayed - blank, NULL, N, etc.  Maybe Athena has such an option either during table creation, import setup, or application wide.

Comment: Thanks, seems like we don't have as such a setting available there. :(

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?